# python adding list inside list unexpected behavior

Tags: python, list, addition

Python 2.7.3 - Debian 7 - 32 bits

I am trying to add lists(*listado*) inside a list(*tabla*), but when *tabla* is printed all the elements in *tabla* are the same and besides it is the last list added !!!!

```
tabla = []
listado = [0,0,0]    
lista_base = range(100)                       

for elemento in lista_base:
    listado[0] = elemento
    listado[1] = elemento+1
    listado[2] = elemento+2
    tabla.append(listado)       # <--- What is wrong here ??
    print(listado)              # <--- This works fine. It is print each *listado*.

print(tabla)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are manipulating *the same list* over and over again, not a copy.

Create a new list in the loop instead:

```
for elemento in lista_base:
    listado = [elemento, elemento + 1, elemento + 2]
    tabla.append(listado)
```

or create a *copy* of the list:

```
for elemento in lista_base:
    listado[0] = elemento
    listado[1] = elemento+1
    listado[2] = elemento+2
    tabla.append(listado[:])
```

where `[:]` returns a full slice of all the elements. You could also use `list(listado)` or import the `copy` module and use `copy.copy(listado)` to create a copy of the existing list.

Appending a list to another list only adds a *reference*, and your code thus created many references to the same list that you kept changing in the loop.

You could have seen what was happening had you printed *tabla* on every loop. Printing `listado` on every loop iteration only shows that the state of that list was correct for that iteration, not that all the references to that list in `tabla` were changing along with it:

```
>>> tabla = []
>>> listado = [0, 0, 0]
>>> for elemento in range(3):
...     listado[0] = elemento
...     listado[1] = elemento+1
...     listado[2] = elemento+2
...     tabla.append(listado)
...     print 'tabla after iteration {}: {!r}'.format(elemento, tabla)
... 
tabla after iteration 0: [[0, 1, 2]]
tabla after iteration 1: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
tabla after iteration 2: [[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Notice how all `tabla` lists change together; they are in fact all the same list. If you create a new list instead, things work as expected:

```
>>> tabla = []
>>> for elemento in range(3):
...     listado = [elemento, elemento + 1, elemento + 2]
...     tabla.append(listado)
...     print 'tabla after iteration {}: {!r}'.format(elemento, tabla)
... 
tabla after iteration 0: [[0, 1, 2]]
tabla after iteration 1: [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
tabla after iteration 2: [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the content of same list, and adding a reference to it in your `tabla`. So, all the lists in the `tabla` will be same as the last `list` added.

You should create a new list each time in the loop. Try changing your loop to:

```
for elemento in lista_base:
    listado = [elemento, elemento+1, elemento+2]
    tabla.append(listado)
```